# Host 3 sites on one server (port 80) accessed by DNS, but lock 2 of them down to requests from within certain subnets?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos, iptables

If I have 3 domain names: siteA, siteB, and siteC.
Lets say all of these sites are stored on the same server, however I want to lock siteB down to only a certain subnet and siteC to a broader subnet.

Is there any way to achieve this using only IPTables and Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, apache's mod_access will take care of this nicely. Throw something like this into the .htaccess for the sites to which you want to restrict access:

```
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.1.0/24
Allow from 1.2.3.4/32
```